# Django persistent API connections between requests

Tags: python, django, persistent-connection

So I have a lot of internal and external APIs that are called on basically each request. This means that there's a lot of setting up connections to these APIs. Is there a way of creating a persistent connection object that can be shared between requests?

So I'd like to replace:

```
def a(request):
    c = api.connect()
    c.call_function()
```

With:

```
def b(request):
    // use existing connection object from earlier request
    c.call_function()
```

Any ideas?

I'm also not sure how big the gain would be but I don't mind doing some benchmarking once I have a first solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quite simple really

```
conn = api.connect() # This line is run only once when the process starts and the module is loaded 

def view(request):
    conn.call_function() # This line is run every time a request is received
```

This connection would be shared by any request using the same worker/server *process*. So if you have three workers serving your application you would have at most three connections.

I would worry that the connections might start timing out. So you would want to guard against that. Perhaps by having a function that checked the state of the connection, returned it if it was still good, or creating a new one if it had expired.

Why this works can be illustrated with the following example:

```
>>> a = 1
>>> def add(b):
...     print a + b
... 
>>> add(2)
3
```

Note that you can't modify the connection without using the global keyword

```
>>> def change(c):
...     a = c
...     print a
... 
>>> change(4)
4
>>> print a
1
```

Compare:

```
>>> a = 1
>>> def change(d):
...     global a
...     a = d
...     print a
... 
>>> change(5)
5
>>> print a
5
>>>
```

If you want to share the api connection between different workers/processes it becomes a bit trickier. i.e don't bother.

Comment: Ehm... it turned out that as long as i don't try to set it it works fine. So accessing conn works but if I try to set conn further down (after reading it) it crashes on the read... I'll updated my question with example.

Comment: Why are you trying to assign to conn? I thought the whole point was persisting a connection? If you want to change the global, you have to use the global keyword.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to aychedee's answer I would suggest you to take a look at [django's database persistent connections](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/databases/#persistent-connections), which are new for Django 1.6. The idea:

> Persistent connections avoid the overhead of re-establishing a connection to the database in each request.

You can implement something similar for your own needs.

Code on Github in [Django's 1.6 branch](https://github.com/django/django/tree/stable/1.6.x/django/db). It's complicated enough but contains connection expiring and usability check logic.

Comment: Thanks, but a bit too much for this project.